# Minimizing GPU's idle time when using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

How can we minimize the idle time of a GPU when training a network using Tensorflow ?

To do this :-

1. I used multiple Python threads to preprocess data and feed it to a `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` from where the TensorFlow took the data.

I thought that this will be more efficient than the `feed_dict` method.

However I still find on doing `nvidia-smi` that my GPU still goes from `100%` utilization to `0%` utilization and back to `100%` quite often. 
Since my network is large and the dataset is also large `12 million`, any fruitful advice on speeding up would be very helpful.

Is my thinking that reading data directly from a `tf.Queue` is better than `feed_dict` correct ?

**NOTE:** I am using a 12 GB Titan X GPU (Maxwell architecture)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct on assuming that feeding through a queue is better than feed_dict, for multiple reasons (mainly loading and preprocessing done on CPU, and not on the main thread). But one thing that can undermine this is if the GPU consume the data faster than it is loaded. You should therefore monitor the size of your queue to check if you have times where the queue size is 0.

If this is the case, I would recommand you to move your threading process into the graph, tensorflow as some nice mecanismes to allow batch loading (your loading batchs should be larger than your training batchs to maximise your loading efficiency, I personnaly use training batchs of 128 and loading batchs of 1024) in threads on CPU very efficiently. Moreover, you should place your queue on CPU and give it a large maximum size, you will be able to take advantage of the large size of RAM memory (I always have more than 16000 images loaded in RAM, waiting for training).

If you still have troubles, you should check tensorflow's performance guide:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance